# Why does my JSON array turn into an object?

Tags: php, json, unset, file-put-contents

I am trying to unset a value from test_bots.json and save it back, but somehow the data format is being changed in the process.

test_bots.json contains this JSON array:

```
["John","Vladimir","Toni","Joshua","Jessica"]
```

My code looks like this:

```
$good = 'Toni';
$good_arr = file_get_contents('test_bots.json');
$good_arr = json_decode($good_arr);

if(in_array($good, $good_arr)){
        $key = array_search($good, $good_arr);
         unset($good_arr[$key]);

        $good_arr2 = json_encode($good_arr);
        file_put_contents('test_bots.json',$good_arr2); 
    }
```

The output that's saved is:

```
{"0":"John","1":"Vladimir","3":"Joshua","4":"Jessica"}
```

but I want the output to look like:

```
["John","Vladimir","Joshua","Jessica"]
```

I tried to unserialize the array before saving it, but it's not working.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Change `$good_arr` in `file_put_contents` to `$good_arr2`.

Comment: Looks like just a typo. As @jardis pointed out, you aren't saving the variable you just created with `json_encode` to the file, you're saving the non-encoded array.

Comment: Sorry that was typo. I edited my question. @Don't Panic

Comment: The culprit here is `array_search()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for `json_encode` to convert a PHP array with numeric keys to a JSON array rather than a JSON object, the keys must be sequential. (See example #4 in [the PHP manual for `json_encode`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))

You can accomplish this in your code by using `array_values`, which will reindex the array after you have removed one of the items.

```
$good_arr2 = json_encode(array_values($good_arr));
```